# How to find the coordinates of a raycaster intersection point on an object in a-frame?

Tags: aframe

I have an entity with the geometry set as plane primitive. How can I know the coordinates of the point on which I clicked (on the entity) using the raycaster/cursor component?

The best would be to the know the coordinates in the system in which the vertices of the geometry were defined at the intersection point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the click event detail for intersection data.

```
el.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
  console.log(evt.detail.intersection);
});
```

This object will contain (https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster):

```
[ { distance, point, face, faceIndex, indices, object }, ... ]
```

So you can use `point` to see where you clicked.

Comment: My event.detail only has cursorEl and target. I'm using fuse to trigger a click, does that change anything?

Comment: My bad, I was working with v0.3.2, realised it works with latest dev build.